# SQL Server : INSERT from one table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am facing a problem regarding inserting data from one table to another table, with the same table structure, but with different column positions.

Example:

Table 1:

```
     emp1:
          Name    char 50
          Age     int
          Salary  Float
```

Table 2:

```
     emp2:
          Name    char 50
          Salary  Float 
          Age     int
```

My code:

```
insert into emp1
select * from emp2
```

I can't insert because the column order is different from one table to the other, but, both tables have same name and data types.

Comment: You have to specify columns

Answer (score 5):

You can (or as @marc_s mentioned **should**) specify columns.

Doing that you can change a structure of these tables (could happen, right?) without any consequences (except if you delete these columns). Your code still working.

Moreover specifying columns name it's just more readable for anybody. You don't need to call `sp_help` or any other commands to check the structure (table schema).

BTW having a primary key in both tables or any table will throw an exception if not specifying the sought columns only:

> If an INSERT statement violates a constraint or rule, or if it has a value incompatible with the data type of the column, the statement fails and an error message is returned.
>
> If INSERT is loading multiple rows with SELECT or EXECUTE, any violation of a rule or constraint that occurs from the values being loaded causes the statement to be stopped, and no rows are loaded.

```
    INSERT INTO emp1 (Name
        ,Age 
        ,Salary )
    SELECT Name
        ,Age 
        ,Salary
    FROM emp2
```

Comment: You *can*, and a best practice says you **always should!**

Comment: @marc_s. =) It's why in comment I mentioned about '**have to**'

Answer (score 0):

test this query , it should work:

```
insert into emp1 select Name, Age, Salary from emp2;
```

and I suggest you to read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just reorder columns during insert:

```
INSERT INTO `emp1` (Name, Salary, Age)
SELECT Name, Salary, Age FROM `emp2`;
```

Comment: if its more than 100 fields , its tedious.