# SQL Server : insert into table

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I am facing a problem regarding inserting data from one table into another table, with the same table structure, but with different column positions.

Example:

Table 1: emp1:

```
Name char 50 
Age int 
Addrs char 100
Salary Float
```

Table 2: emp2

```
Name char 50 
Salary Float 
Age int

insert into emp1 
    select * 
    from emp2
```

I am getting error

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Please let me know the solution, the possible way to get it done.

Comment: You already have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44463748/330315

Comment: You have **just asked the *SAME* question** only two hours ago - and you have **gotten ANSWER** that solve your problem - please **DO NOT** repost this over and over and over again !

Answer (score 0):

Define your columns in your INSERT and SELECT statements. It's best practice to do this always, since if your table structure changes your SELECT * will be broken (as you have found).

```
INSERT INTO emp1 (name, age, salary)
SELECT name, age salary
FROM emp2
```